# maven-frontend-plugin build error

Tags: maven, npm, angular

I have been working on getting angular 2 setup in eclipse. I ran into an error when setting up maven. I am relatively new to maven and I am unsure on how to overcome the error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) @ BudgetCalculator ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in /Users/csexton/Eclipse-Workspace/REST/BudgetCalculator
[INFO] budget_calculator@1.0.0 /Users/csexton/Eclipse-Workspace/REST/BudgetCalculator
[INFO] +-- angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 
[INFO] +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-shim@^0.35.0
[INFO] +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY reflect-metadata@0.1.2
[INFO] +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
[INFO] `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.6.12
[INFO] 
[WARNING] npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
[WARNING] npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2 but none was installed.
[WARNING] npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
[WARNING] npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.12 but none was installed.
[WARNING] npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON budget_calculator@1.0.0 No description
[WARNING] npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON budget_calculator@1.0.0 No repository field.
[WARNING] npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON budget_calculator@1.0.0 No license field.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm run build) @ BudgetCalculator ---
[INFO] Running 'npm run build' in /Users/csexton/Eclipse-Workspace/REST/BudgetCalculator
[ERROR] npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
[ERROR] npm ERR! argv "/Users/csexton/Eclipse-Workspace/REST/BudgetCalculator/node/node" "/Users/csexton/Eclipse-Workspace/REST/BudgetCalculator/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
[ERROR] npm ERR! node v5.3.0
[ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! missing script: build
[ERROR] npm ERR! 
[ERROR] npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     /Users/csexton/Eclipse-Workspace/REST/BudgetCalculator/npm-debug.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.356 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-29T14:36:25-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

two things I can see right off that could be problems but I have no idea how to solve or why it caused the error: `npm ERR! missing script: build` &

```
[INFO] +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-shim@^0.35.0
[INFO] +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY reflect-metadata@0.1.2
[INFO] +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
[INFO] `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.6.12
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "budget_calculator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
    "es6-shim":"^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata":"0.1.2",
    "rxjs":"5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js":"^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

pom.xml portion of what I used to install plugins

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>

            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v5.3.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>3.3.12</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing these dependencies in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "es6-shim":"^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata":"0.1.2",
    "rxjs":"5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js":"^0.6.12"
}
```

You are also missing a script named `build`, you can add it in `package.json`, because in you `pom.xml`, you have `<id>npm run build</id>`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "..."
  },
  "dependencies": {
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: that fixed the unmet peer dependencies but didn't solve the npm error. See edit for package.json and pom.xml